# Calculate the effect of the change of bond price

Tags: bond

I have the following question from Hull, [problem 6.14](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwirvZa_6d7XAhXDEbwKHVXPCIcQFghEMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffinpko.faculty.ku.edu%2Fmyssi%2Findex.php%3Fdir%3DFIN832%2FChapter%2520Problem%2520Solutions%2FHull%25209th%2520Edition%2F%26file%3DHullFund9eCh06ProblemSolutions.doc&usg=AOvVaw0R0H4SHBW8zlbAXHo2UHVI):

---

*A five-year bond with a yield of 11% (continuously compounded) pays an 8% coupon at the end of each year.*

***(c)** Use the duration to calculate the effect on the bond’s price of a 0.2% decrease in its yield.*

---

The solution is as follows:

*Since, with the notation in the chapter*
$$\begin{align}\Delta B & = -BD\Delta y \qquad (1)\end{align}$$
*the effect on the bond’s price of a 0.2% decrease in its yield is:*
$$\$86.80\times4.256\times 0.002 = 0.74$$

---

However the bonds price *B* is \$86.80, and the $\Delta y$ indicates a change, where by notation a decrease is negative, and an increase is positive. So based from this, and using formula (1) shouldn't the equation be:

$$-\$86.80 \times 4.256 \times(-0.002) = 0.74$$

---

Question:

Is this a mistake in the text book, or is my approach incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highly off-topic, but you are correct. The book however is not wrong, the authors just canceled out the negatives to provide short solutions. The solutions tend to be rather brief if i remember correctly.